# How can I add to this command to make "notifications" via a new terminal pops up with a message?

Tags: linux, bash, watch

I am using this command via a script:

```
watch "who | egrep -i 'user1|user2|user3'"
```

I am trying to get this to make a new terminal pop up and say:

"user has logged on"

I would like to run everything in the background with "&" but as one of the users in the command login I would like to have this script pop up a new terminal and say this user is logged in.

I want it to only happen when they log in and if they log out and log back it.

I understand if I run the initial command in the foreground I can watch my "custom" list of users log in and off every 2 seconds BUT I am looking to run it all in the background and have the new terminal pop up with the specific user who logged in.

I am sorry for repeating myself but I am trying to be specific as possible.

Comment: Maybe, try [`notify-send`](http://man.cx/notify-send) instead of terminal window.

Comment: A new terminal or some sort of desktop notification window? Also this seems like a very bad way to get that sort of notification. I would think something watching syslog would be better or even better would be some sort of system accounting/tracking solution.

Comment: @anishsane I will look into that, I'm just trying to figure out a way to get that instance of the user login to echo to a new term or notification.

Comment: @Etan Reisner I could only imagine as someone who is unfamiliar with all of this, the numerous amount of better avenues there are at getting this done. I am just attempting to go about it as a newb and find a short script to notify my when a user on the local system logs into their account is all.

Comment: You really need to write a daemon or something.  You need to detect differences in the output in order to display them, not just the output.  IE, you need to detect new lines in 'who' output, or as someone else suggested, new lines in a syslog file that matched how people are coming into the system (eg, via ssh).  `kdialog` is a useful utility for doing popup messages though.  `kdialog --passivepopup "user42 is online"`

Comment: @Wes Hardaker I understand that is probably the best way to go I just am not following at all about what I need to write script wise to do something like that. I know how to get data from who and thats about it. It has been suggested that I use two text documents for currently on and off users and use watch and now monitor log files. But my lack of experience is what keeps me from getting to the end result of anyone of these solutions. I can only keep reading on and on! Thanks for your input as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`watch` is good to watch a command output, but not to work on it.

I would suggest using a loop, wich saves the output between iterations and check for diff. Somethink like this:

```
last_output=$(tempfile)
output=$(tempfile)

while true; do
  who | egrep -i 'user1|user2|user3' > $output

  # check for new users logged
  new_users=$(diff $last_output $output | grep '>' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

  # if there is some, throw a notification
  if [ -n "$new_users" ]; then
    xterm -e "echo -e 'New users logged:\n$new_users'; read -n 1" &
  fi

  # we save the output
  mv $output $last_output

  sleep 2
done
```

Here I use xterm to throw a notification, but you can use others tools like `libnotify` (wich provides `notify-send`). And because xterm stops when the executed command is finished, I add the `read -n 1` command who waits for an input, but you can use `sleep` to make the notification disappear without an user interaction.

**Edit**

To read the list of users to watch from a file, you can use something like this (with a file containing one user per line) :

```
regex=$(tr '\n' '|' < path/to/file)
regex=${regex%?} # to remove the last '|'
```

Comment: Seems like the road I have gotten close to, though I am getting a few error this is really something I was trying to figure out! Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: How do I pull a list of users from a file versus putting names straight into the script?